# Read the data from XML file into flat files(txt) and with formated data

Tags: c#, xml, text

I have an XML file with nodes and data...I need to write that into a text file as normal data. The nodes being the headers of the data
that follow.

EG XML:

```
<Bank>
<accountholder>Georgina Wax</accountholder>
<accountnumber>408999703657</accountnumber>
<accounttype>cheque</accounttype>
<bankname>National Bank</bankname>
<branch>Africa</branch>
<amount>2750.00</amount>
<date>12/01/2012</date>
</Bank>
```

To txt file and formatted as :

accountholder       accountnumber   accounttype bankname
Georgina Wax            408999703657    cheque      National Bank

I can't seem to have it to have spaces between the data and hearders.

Below is what I tried :

```
 StreamWriter writer = File.CreateText(@"C:\\Test.txt");
 XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
 doc.Load(@"C:\\bank.xml");
       writer.WriteLine(string.Join("|",doc.SelectSingleNode("/debitorders/deduction").ChildNodes.C    ast<XmlElement>().Select(e =>    doc.SelectSingleNode("/debitorders/deduction/bankname").ToString())));

  foreach (XmlElement book in doc.SelectNodes("/debitorders/deduction"))
            {
                writer.WriteLine(book.ChildNodes.Cast<XmlElement>().Select(e =>    e.InnerText).ToArray());
            }
```

Please help.

Comment: Any .NET version restrictions? If not, I might be able to help.

Comment: @Jeff no restrictions. And your help is more than welcome.

Comment: Can you refer what kind of output you like in your text file ??

Comment: @MuhammadUmar yes I have specified on the question under the "To txt file and formatted as" section but of course I want it to have spaces between the headers and data. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will produce output like you want.

```
private static void LoadAndWriteXML()
    {
        string headerFiles = "";
        string values = "";
        using (XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(@"C:\\bank.xml"))
        {
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                if (reader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element && !reader.Name.Equals("Bank"))   // we have to skip root node means bank node.
                {
                    headerFiles += reader.Name + " ";
                    values += reader.ReadString() + " ";
                }
            }
        }

        StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(@"C:\\Test.txt");

        writer.WriteLine(headerFiles.Trim());
        writer.WriteLine(values.Trim());

        writer.Close();


    }
```

Comment: Thanks this is it but there is still no equal spacing between records. But yes it works. +1 from me. I will update your answer once i'm done with it.

Comment: And if we have multiple records on the XML file it aligns it badly. Can you help with putting multiple records in different lines no same line.

Comment: Find something common in records so that you will append new line according to this on your string.

Answer (score 0):

```
XDocument xdoc = new XDocument();
xdoc = XDocument.Load(fname);
xdoc.Save(fname1);
```

will save the file with the tags alignment formating

Comment: no no no no that is not what I'm looking for, please refer to the question again.